# Average from two list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two list of dictionaries and I want to find the average of values from each of them based upon the key value. i.e I want to match the keys and average its values from list of dictionaries.

```
data = {'5649a533c95a8a0bc345d1fe': [{'1': 0.0}, {'2': 28652.343535112403}, {'3': 26505.012833437846}],
        '5649a533c95a8a0bc345d20c': [{'1': 28652.343535112403}, {'2': 26505.012833437846}, {'3': 24518.570421292356}]}
```

I want to match the keys i.e `'1'` in both the list of dictionaries and then do the average of its respective values.

E.g In the above dataset, I need to get the values `0.0` and `28652.343535112403` matched by the keys i.e '1' and then do the average of the values.

The expected result is `[{'1': 20000}, {'2': 230000}, {'3': 23000}]`

I am able to iterate the dictionary but I am lost after that.

This is what I have tried to do

```
for k, v in data.items():
    for index, i in enumerate(v, start=1):
        print(index, i[str(index)])
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
d = {}

for x in itertools.chain(data.values()):
        for k,v in x.items():
            if k in d:
                d[k].append(v)
            else:
                d[k] = [v]

av = {}

for k,v in d.items():
    av[k]=sum(v)/len(v)

print av
```

I got a results:

```
{'1': 14326.171767556201, '3': 25511.7916273651, '2': 27578.678184275122}
```

**Note:** Based on your values on data, you cant have the average:

```
[{'1': 20000}, {'2': 230000}, {'3': 23000}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another try may be-

```
d = []
for k, v in data.items():
    dd = []
    for index, i in enumerate(v, start=1):
        dd.append((index, i[str(index)]))
    d.append(dd)
av_1 = []
av_2 = []

for (x,y) in zip(d[0],d[1]):
    l1 = (x[0],y[0])
    l2= (x[01],y[1])
    l1_av = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l1) / len(l1)
    l2_av = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l2) / len(l2)
    av_1.append(l1_av)
    av_2.append(l2_av)
print {k:v for k,v in zip(av_1,av_2)}
```

Output

```
{1: 14326.171767556201, 2: 27578.678184275122, 3: 25511.7916273651}
```